# “The item that you requested is not available for purchase” Error in my ionic android app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to integrate in-app purchases with (cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inapppurchase) into my app, but unfortunately coming across this annoying error "The item that you requested is not available for purchase".
I have done all this :

1.Apk signed and published, with same version on Developer Console and on device account on device is the same listed on Developer Console for tests and is not the same as mine.

2.Product active on Developer Console.

but still it's showing not available for purchase.

Answer (score 0):

> *****Add Android Billing Key***

Your license key for in-app billing should be added manually to your project. This key is found in Services and API in the Google Play Developer Console.

The license key is set during installation:

```
cordova plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.purchase --variable BILLING_KEY="MIIB...AQAB"

Replace MIIB...AQAB with your own android license key.
```

To change it, remove the plugin and add it back with the new key.**

> Create New Products on Android

Add in-app purchases items from the Developer Console
Activate them
No need to publish the app.
Purchase types:

for consumable, non consumable and non-renewing subscriptions choose "managed".
for free and paid subscriptions, choose "subscriptions".

Comment: I'm using this plugin :
https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase

and i had added BILLING_KEY to the www/manifest.json file as it is mentioned in this tutorial 
https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the controller it is fetching item details price correctly , but when i buy any of the item it gives the error (The item that you requested is not available for purchase)

var productIds = ['com.ionicframework.****7.productone','com.ionicframework.***7.producttwo']; // 
  var spinner = '
';

$scope.loadProducts = function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Loading Products...' });
    inAppPurchase
      .getProducts(productIds)
      .then(function (products) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $scope.products = products;
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

$scope.buy = function (productId) {

```
$ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Purchasing...' });
inAppPurchase
  .buy(productId)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log('consuming transactionId: ' + data.transactionId);
    return inAppPurchase.consume(data.type, data.receipt, data.signature);
  })
  .then(function () {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Purchase was successful!',
      template: 'Check your console log for the transaction data'
    });
    alert('consume done!');
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
 [enter image description here][1]
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Something went wrong',
      template: JSON.stringify(err)
    });
  });
```

};

$scope.restore = function () {
    $ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Restoring Purchases...' });
    inAppPurchase
      .restorePurchases()
      .then(function (purchases) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();

```
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Restore was successful!',
      template: 'Check your console log for the restored purchases data'
    });
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: 'Something went wrong',
      template: JSON.stringify(err)
    });
  });
```

};